# Understanding Unity's Mono Behaviour's start() execution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am absolutely confused and therefore simply hope that I am able to describe my issue sufficiently.

I have a class `Test` inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`. It takes a `UnityEngine.UI.Button` array `buttons` as a constructor parameter.

Later the first element of this button array is read. However, this resulted in an out of bounds exception. So, I tried to debug the problem by adding helpful logs. That resulted in:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class Hacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*
     * Handels the hacking panel
     * Once the hacking panel is opened, numbers will randomly appear and the player tries to create a number that fulfills the condition written at the right side.
     */
    public Button[] buttons;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print("Start");
        print("Length: " + buttons.Length);
        // add on Click methods
        foreach (Button button in buttons)
        {
            print("Loop");
            print("Button: " + button);
        }
        print(buttons[0]);
    }
}
```

The crazy thing is that this logs as:

```
Start
Length: 0
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of an array.
Length: 1
Loop
Button buttonname (UnityEngine.UI.Button)
buttonname (UnityEngine.UI.Button)
```

1. Why does the `Length` print appears twice? I think it might be some kind of rescuing by UnrealEngine.
2. Why does it first run with an empty list? How am I supposed to handle that?

Comment: You don't accidentally have a second Hacking component in your scene? Make sure your logs are not collapsed, and see if "Start" gets logged twice.

Comment: Check if there are multiple instances of the `GameObject` with the `Hacking` script attached in your scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start indeed runs only once.

After the line

```cs
print("Start");
```

add the line

```
print(gameObject.GetInstanceID());
```

Run the code again and see if you get two different instance IDs.
If you do, the chances are that you attached the script `Hacking` to more than one GameObject.

If not, check if you accidentally attached the same script twice on the same object.

Comment: You are right. The script was attached to another component. I thought about using `gameObject.name` to check this, but thought that I would see `start` twice if this was the issue. Maybe I just missed the second start or the logging function did something weird. Thank you.

Comment: You likely have "Collapse" enabled in your console.